# Type hints when unpacking a tuple?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, python-typing, iterable-unpacking

Is it possible to use type hinting when unpacking a tuple?  I want to do this, but it results in a `SyntaxError`:

```
from typing import Tuple

t: Tuple[int, int] = (1, 2)
a: int, b: int = t
#     ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Since the types of the variables are already inferred from the unpacked values, you actually don't need to add type hints to them.

Comment: @Jeyekomon If the type inference is correct. Suppose my tuple comes from a function `def f() -> Tuple[int, int]: return 1, 2` and my unpacked `a, b = f()` both want `a: float` and `b: float`.

Comment: If your function returns a tuple of integers, the variables `a` and `b` will contain integers. No matter which type hints you'll use.

Comment: @Jeyekomon Indeed they will immediately after that assignment, but if I know `a` and `b` *should* be floats, and will contain floats later, then I'd like to hint them as floats regardless of what function gives their initial value or what hinting it has.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do. The important point is - if those variables should be floats and you type hint them as floats, you should not assign an integer to them. It is not a good coding practice. Any variable should not change its type during its life. It will confuse other people, it will make linters complain. One of the many solutions to that is `a, b = (float(x) for x in f())`.

Comment: @Jeyekomon Ok, yes that is a really good point. Sorry I didn't understand you earlier.

Answer (score 171, accepted):

According to [PEP-0526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/#global-and-local-variable-annotations), you should annotate the types first, then do the unpacking

```
a: int
b: int
a, b = t
```

Comment: Still triggers a warning:
Redeclared 'a' defined above without usage

Comment: @tribbloid I get that when I have indeed already defined `a` earlier, are you certain you haven't done that?

Comment: @tribbloid This is if the variable is redefined, like `a = int(a)` or other re-assignments. If you work with mypy for static type checking, use `--allow-redefinition` to avoid the warning

Comment: this is sad, how on earth <variable>:<typehint> can not use any syntactical context, where variable assignment is legal...

Answer (score 12):

In my case i use the `typing.cast` function to type hint an unpack operation.

```
t: tuple[int, int] = (1, 2)
a, b = t

# type hint of a -> Literal[1]
# type hint of b -> Literal[2]
```

By using the `cast(new_type, old_type)` you can cast those ugly literals into integers.

```
from typing import cast

a, b = cast(tuple[int, int], t)

# type hint of a -> int
# type hint of b -> int
```

This can be useful while working with Numpy NDArrays with `Unknown` types

```
# type hint of arr -> ndarray[Unknown, Unknown]

a, b = cast(tuple[float, float], arr[i, j, :2]

# type hint of a -> float
# type hint of b -> float
```