# How to apply typing to python destructuring assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, python-typing

How can I add typing to a destructuring assignment in python 3?

This example assignment, does not work because `a:int, b:int = return_tuple()` is not valid:

```py
from typing import Tuple

def return_tuple() -> Tuple[int, int]:
    return 0, 0
        
a:int, b:int = return_typle()
```

We can see this is not valid because running `mypy` returns

```
foo.py:7: error: invalid syntax
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type hints when unpacking a tuple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52082939/type-hints-when-unpacking-a-tuple)